# How can I make it so HTML links can go to different websites?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm making a website using glitch.com and am trying to redirect the user to an external website. Whenever I click on the links, it just says `https://utili.glitch.me/link` rather than the website. How can I make it so it can send the user to an external website?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `http://`, `https://` or `//` before url to redirect your link to another page, Check updated code below

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" title="">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://utili.glitch.me/link">view our website</a>
```

**try this code**

Comment: I'm already using `<a href ="link">link</a>` to attempt to redirect them. I'm wanting it to be as if `<a href ="google.com">google</a>` would go to google.com rather than utili.glitch.me/google.com

Comment: @blackhoodiedood , that's not  how links work. More specifically that's not how urls/paths work. Investigate the difference between [absolute and relative paths/urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs).